# How to deploy a Node.js application in Heroku using WebStorm?

Tags: node.js, heroku, webstorm

I want to deploy my Node.js application in Heroku using WebStorm. I have an account with Heroku.

How to configure in WebStorm? Can any one explain the procedure in simple manner?

Answer (score 0):

WebStorm provides no support for Heroku, full Clouds support is only available in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate.
There is a third-party [Heroku Integration plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6659?pr=idea), but It's not compatible with WebStorm 2017.x. Seems this plugin is discontinued - see https://github.com/jexp/jetbrains-heroku-plugin/issues/38
If you miss official support for Heroku in WebStorm, please vote for [WEB-15174](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-15174)